# Open With dialog does not remember newly added program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, open-with

I use VS2010 every day, and like to sometimes open a c# file (or other file) in another Editor (my favorite Notepad++). So right-clicking on a file in 'Solution Explorer', and choosing Open With..., comes up with the Open With dialog.

I add my editor, and the program appears in the Open With dialog whole day long.

But every time i reboot (or logoff and logon again on the domain), the program is gone from the Open With dialog.

I think this could might have something to do with the roaming profile (because this happens on the job). And consulting our servicedesk did not solve this.

So I did look into the registry, trying to find the place where the programs are stored from the 'Open With' dialog in VS2010. But did not find the right key.

Can anybody tell me where the Open With dialog programs are stored? So i can create a script or something to add my favorite program every time i logon?

Comment: I can't believe this question had no upvotes. This drives me crazy when I want to open an image in PhotoShop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look with SysInternals' Procmon (science!) revealed

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\x.x\Default Editors\yyy
```

where x.x is the VS version number (like 9.0 for VS2008) and yyy is the filename extension.  That key gets a sub-key with the same name as the "Friendly name" and a default value that's set to "Program name". I can't guess why the registry setting doesn't get preserved on your machine, ask questions about that at superuser.com or your "servicedesk".

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans! This works for me. You don't know how much frustration on my site you just took away :-)